# How to remove underscore from column name after transposing data

Tags: sas

How to remove underscore from column name after transposing data

there are around 80 90 columns of date and renaming each column is not the good choice , how to achieve it ?

Original data

[image]

Required data

[image]

Comment: Why would you want column names that are not valid variable names?  Perhaps you are looking to produce a REPORT instead of a dataset?  If so then PROC REPORT could generate a report like your second photograph directly from the "tall" dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS variable names follow SAS naming conventions, in your case a variable name can not start with a digit, but you can bypass this rule by using `options validvarname=any;` before using the transpose procedure. Default value for `validvarname` is `V7`.

From the [SAS documentation: Rules for SAS Variable Names](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lrcon/p18cdcs4v5wd2dn1q0x296d3qek6.htm), when using `options validvarname=V7;` (default), variable name follows these rules:

> - The name can be up to 32 bytes in length.
> - The name can contain letters of the Latin alphabet, numerals, or underscores.
> - The name cannot contain blanks or special characters except for the underscore.
> - **The name must begin with a letter of the Latin alphabet (A–Z, a–z) or the
>   underscore.**
> - Trailing blanks are ignored. The name alignment is left-justified.
> - The name can contain mixed–case letters.

When using `options validvarname=any;` rules are:

> - The name can be up to 32 bytes in length.
> - The name can contain any characters, including blanks, national characters, special characters, and multi-byte characters. Names
>   containing these types of characters must be specified as name
>   literals.
> - **The name can begin with any characters, including blanks, national characters, special characters, and multi-byte characters.**
> - The name cannot contain any null bytes.
> - Leading blanks are preserved but trailing blanks are ignored.
> - The name must contain at least one character. A name with all blanks is not permitted.
> - It can contain mixed-case letters.

---

However, I would not recommend bypassing SAS naming conventions.
I would rather use the [`PREFIX`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1r2tjnp8ewe3sn1acnpnrs3xbad.htm) optional argument to construct names for transposed variables.
For example, if `PREFIX=DATE_`, then the names of the variables would be `DATE_31Dec2022`, `DATE_31Jan2023`, …, `DATE_31May2023`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce that second photograph then produce it directly without creating an intermediate dataset.  Then you do not need to try to force SAS to use date values as variable names.

```
proc report data=have;
  columns system lan value,date ;
  define system / group;
  define lan / group;
  define value / ' ';
  define date / across order=internal format=date9. ' ';
run;
```